# COUNTIFS Date contains this month - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Column A contains Datevalues.
Column B a String.
I would like to count all cells where A is this month and B contains a certain String.

Here is my approach: `=COUNTIFS(B1:B; "Certain String"; MONTH(A1:A); MONTH(TODAY()))`

Unfortunately this approach does not work. Any idea?

Comment: your approach wasn't bad, however "A1:A" part requires array formula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B;"Certain String";A:A;">"&eomonth(Today();-1);A:A;"<="&eomonth(Today();0))
```

Does not count this month in other than this year.

Answer (score 1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIFS(B:B, "string", MONTH(A:A), "="&MONTH(TODAY())))
```

[image]